# cannot register a node (VM) with selenium grid 2 hub (physical machine)

Tags: selenium, grid

I al trying to register a node which is a VM with windows 7 on a hub that sits on a physical machine windows 7 also.
My server starts succesfully on port 4444.
I run this command to register the node : 
This is what i get from my node console :

```
C:\grid>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node -hub http://
hubip:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS -
rowser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS -browser "browserName=internet explo
er,platform=WINDOWS" -remoteHost nodeip:4444
26 sept. 2013 11:28:40 org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a selenium grid node
26 sept. 2013 11:28:40 org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest addCapability
romString
INFO: Adding browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS
26 sept. 2013 11:28:40 org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest addCapability
romString
INFO: Adding browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS
26 sept. 2013 11:28:40 org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest addCapability
romString
INFO: Adding browserName=internet explorer,platform=WINDOWS
11:28:41.375 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.13-b02
11:28:41.375 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 x86
11:28:41.375 INFO - v2.35.0, with Core v2.35.0. Built from revision c916b9d
11:28:41.531 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: ://127.0.0
1:5555/wd/hub
11:28:41.531 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
11:28:41.531 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-serve
/driver]
11:28:41.531 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
11:28:41.531 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
11:28:41.546 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@111a3
4
11:28:41.546 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
11:28:41.546 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
11:28:41.546 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@a9ae05
11:28:41.546 INFO - using the json request : {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.R
gistrationRequest","capabilities":[{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"
INDOWS","browserName":"firefox"},{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"WI
DOWS","browserName":"chrome"},{"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","platform":"WINDO
S","browserName":"internet explorer"}],"configuration":{"port":5555,"host":"10.
128.120","hubHost":"192.168.1.110","registerCycle":5000,
"hub":"://hubip:4444/grid/register","url":"nodeip:4444","remoteHost":"
nodeip:4444","register":true,"proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.Defau
tRemoteProxy","maxSession":5,"browser":"browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS","
ole":"node","hubPort":4444}}
11:28:41.546 INFO - Starting auto register thread. Will try to register every 5
00 ms.
11:28:41.546 INFO - Registering the node to hub :://hubip:4444/grid
register
11:29:56.910 INFO - Registering the node to hub :://hubip:4444/grid
register
11:31:12.274 INFO - Registering the node to hub :://hubip:4444/grid
register
11:32:27.684 INFO - Registering the node to hub :://hubip:4444/grid
register
11:33:43.204 INFO - Registering the node to hub :://hubip:4444/grid
register
11:34:58.599 INFO - Registering the node to hub :://hubip:4444/grid
register
```

--- the node keeps trying to register but the registration is refused.

Here is what i get from the hub console :

```
Avertissement: Unregistering the node. It's been down for 60113 milliseconds.
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:04 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry removeIfPresent
Avertissement: Proxy 'nodeip:4444 time out : 300000' was prev
iously registered.  Cleaning up any stale test sessions.
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:07 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy <init>
Avertissement: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:07 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy <init>
Avertissement: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:07 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.BaseRemoteProxy <init>
Avertissement: Max instance not specified. Using default = 1 instance
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:13 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy isA
live
Avertissement: Failed to check status of node: Connection to nodeip
:4444 refused
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:19 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy isA
live
Avertissement: Failed to check status of node: Connection to nodeip
:4444 refused
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:19 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy onE
vent
Avertissement: Marking the node as down. Cannot reach the node for 2 tries.
sept. 26, 2013 12:00:25 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy isA
live
Avertissement: Failed to check status of node: Connection to nodeip
:4444 refusedsept. 26, 2013 12:00:31 PM
```

Comment: FYI : I have tried the same with a hub and node on the same machine when I run the command to launch the hub all is fin, then once I run the command to register the node I got the registration text and it gets blocked with no error messages at all!!! any clue please??

Comment: Hi, I have managed to solve the issue, I had a typo in my java remote control constructor pointing into the wrong IP!!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please post the solution

Comment: Here is the command : start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-%SELENIUM_VERSION%.jar -role node 
-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver= %CHROME_DRIVER_LOC% -hub %HUB_URL% -port 5556

Comment: Instead of using the hub and node concept you could directly run the the selenium jar file without the -hub extension in the virtual machine and make changes in your code accordingly..just a suggestion